# AppLinks in iOs app How to pass data to a freshly installed app

Tags: ios, facebook

If I have a iOs app that has multiple content that a user can access, can I do the following:
Allow a user that is currently consuming a content (stream radio/some streamed video) to post from the app to his Facebook page "I am currently viewing X using APP".(this is clearly doable)
Another user that has the app installed can  click the link will be redirected from the Facebook app to my app (o app links seem to be the solution in this case). If the user that clicks the link does not have the app installed Facebook will ask him to install the required app. I understand that all this is possible using Facebook iOs SDK and App Links.

My question is after the user installs the app how will I direct him to the original content in the link (X)? Is this handled automatically by Apple/Facebook? Or will I need a backend server which will track what the user tapped on before downloading the app?

Can the same be done from the native iOs twitter app?